# Creating new collection on every POST request NodeJS + Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How to create a new collection on every POST request on NodeJS express + mongoose based REST API ?

There are lot of tutorials that uses the same collection hard-coded, but can't find one which allows to create new collection on every new POST.

For example:
`model.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       //Scehma Here
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('mycollection', mySchema);
```

and `server.js`

```
var devices = require('./model');
router.route('/devices')
  .post(function(req, res) {
    var device = new devices();
        device._id = req.body.id;
        device.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
              res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'Success!' });
        });
  })
```

This creates new document on the `mycollection` for every new `POST`

But, I need to isolate every new object created in to a new collection.

Is it possible to create a new collection on every POST with the same schema and collection name being `req.body.id`

#### Update:

Usecase for @chridam and  @MykolaBorysyuk comments

The data will be timeseries data from lot of IoT devices.

On the first connect, the device will do a `POST` request with its `ID` like IMEI and from then it will send data continuously every 5 secs.
To store something like here: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb

I thought creating a new collection for each device will be good idea, if thats a bad choice (I'm DevOps and new to Development), please suggest me a better approach for the above use case. It will be 100s of devices with  continuous time series data.

Thank you.

Comment: Just being curious, why would you want to create a collection for each HTTP POST request?

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306916/dynamically-create-collection-w-mongoose

Comment: Basically you can using mongoDb driver. But it's very bad approach. You may want to rethink your logic and find better solution.

Comment: Thanks @MykolaBorysyuk Updated the question with use case, please suggest me a better approach for the same

I'm new to  NodeJS and NoSQL DBs

Comment: If you can that just make in mongo _id = thatDeviceUniqueId and store that values there. So you will have documents something like this {_id: deviceId, data: [Array of that data that you want..]}. And just on each post update data array

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk Thanks, let me try that

Answer (score 0):

I think @MykolaBorysyuk suggestion is valid but if you would want to use [capped collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) to limit the number of documents that will be kept per device then separate collections is the better approach.