# Create mongodb collections of a JSON response key value

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new in MongoDb and NodeJS. I want to create collections of a table.

Here is my **JSON** response :-

```
{
    "_id": "5c85f83516f5ad7ef3e14",
    "companyName": "XYZ",
    "fullName": "ABC",
    "designation": "Software Engineer",
    "companyID": "14224",
}
```

Here I am getting an unique `companyID` for a particular  `companyName`. I want to create as many collections as much there will be unique `companyID`. How can I achieve it by NodeJS , ExpressJS code ?

**EDIT:-** *controller file.*

```
module.exports.registerAdmin = (req, res, next) =>{ 
    var admin = new Admin();
    admin.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    admin.email = req.body.email;
    admin.password = req.body.password;
    admin.fullName = req.body.fullName;

//----creating hash token for email verification ------------
const secret = crypto.randomBytes(20);
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
                   .update(secret + admin.email)
                   .digest('hex');

//comapny id generate
const reqq = crypto.createHash('md5').update(admin.companyName).digest('hex');
let valueNum = reqq.match(/\d/g).join("").toString().substring(0,6);

admin.companyID = valueNum;

    //saving users data to database
    admin.save((err, doc) =>{
        if(!err){
            res.send(doc);
                let coSchema = coName => {
                    return {
                        id: {type: String, index: true},
                        coName: {default: coName}
                    }
                }

                response.then((data) => {
                    let coSchema;
                    data.forEach((doc) => {
                        coSchema = coSchema(doc.companyID);
                        mongoose.model(doc.companyID, coSchema);
                    })
                }
        }
        else{
            if (err.code == 11000)
                    res.status(422).send(["Entered duplicate email address. Please check"]);
            else
            return next(err);
            }
    });
}
```

**Model :=**

```
var adminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    companyName : {
                type: String,
                required: "Company  name can't be empty.",
                required: false
                },  
    companyID:  {
                type: String,
                unique: true
                },          
    email :     {
                type: String,
                required: "Email can't be empty.",
                unique: true
                },
    password:   {
                type: String,
                required: "First name can't be empty."
                },
    fullName: {
                type: String,
                required: "First name can't be empty."
                },
designation :   {
                type: String,
                required: "Designation can't be empty."
                }           
});

mongoose.model('Admin', adminSchema);
```

Comment: _I want to create as many collections as there will be unique companyID_ you mean documents right ? not collection ?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey No , not documents. I need to create collections. Within a DBS I need to create collections with `companyIDs` values ie; 14224 , 34344 ,54454 etc

Comment: So you are working on a multi tenent application? with multiple collection for each client? check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306916/dynamically-create-collection-with-mongoose

Comment: @AZ_ Yes. You are correct

Comment: @AZ_ It didn't helped much .

Answer (score 0):

define your company Schema inside a function which accepts the com name and return the schema object.

say response is the array of documents read from db, parse through each and create a collection as per company Name, ensure company name is defined unique i your response schema

```js
let coSchema = coName => {
 return {
  id: {type: String, index: true}, //need to have index created on some unique value to get the schema created without documents.
  coName: {default: coName}
  //add your feilds
 }
}

response.then((data) => {
 let coSchema;
 data.forEach((doc) => {
  coSchema = coSchema(doc.companyID);
  mongoose.model(doc.companyID, coSchema);
 })
})
```

Handle your promises accordingly.

Comment: Should i try this in controller or model ? As I need to pass the function when registration happens in controller save function I guess.

Comment: depends if you need company name also in your schema if not you can create a default model for all tenants.

Comment: I have added the controller in my EDIT.  Am I doing it right ? When I  am passing  `let coSchema = admin.companyName` showing error  `Unexpected token .`

Comment: I want empty collection at first. As I am use those collections with different schemas

Comment: my code is just an example to achieve what you are trying to do, you cant simply copy paste it in your already developed code.

Comment: where you have added let coSchema = admin.companyName ?

Comment: Ok got it. I am adding model file also in EDIT plz have a look

Comment: Here you said "response is the array of documents read from db" , but it is being created with the same API. whatever the  `companyID` in the response, will be the new collection with unique ID only. Not similar

Comment: ohh ok, I thought its something like an inner join, if you are getting it from some api, you don't need to use forEach and all.

Comment: The response will going to be created in with this api only where I am creating the function.