# Access an existing monogodb collection using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building an app using Nodejs where I need to perform some functions on a collection on the server side. I have been told to use mongoose to get access to the collection. Here is my code so far:

```
        var mongoose = require('mongoose');
        var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err){
            if(!err){
                console.log("no error!")
            }
        });
        var doc = mongoose.model('foo', 
                       new Schema({name : String}), 
                       'answers'); 
        doc.find({}, function(err,collection){ 
          console.log(collection)
        });
```

The collection that I want access to is called 'answers'. I want to access the data and make some changes and post those to a another collection. The code above printed an empty array. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: Looks like you've created a model, but not added anything to the DB yet, which is why you get an empty collection back

Comment: I did add stuff to the Db before using mongoose. I checked it and the data is in the collection.

Comment: Code looks fine. Are you sure the `answers` collection is in the `test` database?

Comment: Is that a pre-existing collection? Was it created before you wrote a model for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794834/how-to-access-a-preexisting-collection-with-mongoose

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', function(err){
        if(!err){
            console.log("no error!")
        }
    });
    var doc = mongoose.model('answer', new Schema(
        {name : String})
    ); 
    doc.find({}, function(err,collection){ 
      console.log(collection)
    });
```