# web page does not receive data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mean, bitnami

I am a beginner.
I installed Bitnami MEAN stack and I have a question.

`"[]"` shows on the web page when I enter http://127.0.0.1:3000/tableList.
I want to know why the web page does not show the data in collections.

On Command Prompt:

> C:\Bitnami\meanstack-3.2.3-1\test>SET DEBUG=test:* & npm start
>
> test@0.0.0 start C:\Bitnami\meanstack-3.2.3-1\test
>   node ./bin/www
>   test:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms
>   connection successful
>   []
>   GET /tableList 304 30.004 ms - -
>   GET /favicon.ico 200 7.164 ms - 1183

On `mongodb.log` file:

> 2016-04-05T00:08:04.350+0700 I NETWORK [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:52192 #6 (4 connections now open)
>   2016-04-05T00:08:04.513+0700 I ACCESS [conn6] Successfully authenticated as principal chai on khamoo

On `app.js` file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://chai:chai@localhost/khamoo', function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('connection error', err);
  } else {
    console.log('connection successful');
  }
});

mongoose.model('tableList',{tid: String});

app.get('/tableList', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.model('tableList').find(function(err,tableList){
    console.log(tableList);
    res.json(tableList);
  });
});
```

Comment: have you checked err?

Comment: what error that I must check?
[] show on web browser and no error when I press F12.
no error on mongodb.log file.

Comment: ** mongoose.model('tableList').find(function(err,tableList){** err variable log it see if there is anything there

Comment: app.get('/tableList', function(req, res) {
 mongoose.model('tableList').find({}, function(err,tableList){
  if(err){
   console.log('error', err);
  } else{
   console.log('no error');
   console.log(tableList);
   res.json(tableList);
  }
  
 });
});

Comment: I insert if-else statement follow you suggest but result no error.

Comment: I found solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794834/how-to-access-a-preexisting-collection-with-mongoose.