# How to Connect/Query Mongoose to an existing Database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-models

I am working on trying to connect a Node/Express server to an existing MongoDB Database/Collection.  I have already successfully connected to the database. However, I am having a tremendously difficult time setting up my models/schema to query.

The MongoDB is MongoDB Atlas and has one collection with over 800,000 documents. The name of the single collection is "delitosCollection".

I have tried the following to with no success:

```
var CrimeData = mongoose.model('DelitosCollection', new Schema({}),'delitosCollection');


mongoose.connection.on('open', function(ref){
    console.log("connected to the mongo server");

   CrimeData.find({}, (err,results) => {
       if(err){
           console.log("ERROR")
           throw err
       }
       console.log("results: ", results.length)
   } )
});
```

I know the connection is working as I am receiving the console.log with no errors. However, results.length is returning 0 when it should be over 800,000. Have spent way too many hours on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794834/how-to-access-a-preexisting-collection-with-mongoose

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty schema for each collection you want to use
and then create a model to be used in your project
the model take 3 parameter
1)name of the model
2)schema name
3)collection name ( from mongodb atlas)

like that

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb uri')
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema, 'user');
```

then you can use the model normally

```
User.find({})
```

Answer (score 0):

connection to mongo db

```
// Connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/[yourDbName]',{useNewUrlParser:true})
    .then(function(){
        console.log('mongoDB connected');
    })
    .catch(function(){
        console.log('Error :');
    })
```

after that you will have to create your schema and then only you can query the database

create your schema like this

```
// Crimes Schema 
const CrimeDetailsSchema= new Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});

const Profile = module.exports = mongoose.model('delitosCollection', CrimeDetailsSchema, 'delitosCollection');
```

after that create your queries

you can get an idea about that in mongoose documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the answer given below, just pass an empty object in schema
like db.model('users', new Schema({}))