# Retrieving data from mongodb stored by pymongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pymongo

I have uploaded data to `MongoDB` by `pymongo` and I want to retrieve it in my `nodeJs`. I am writing `function` like this but it is not working. my `collection` name is `linux_trace` and my `database` name is `Linux_Trace_db`.

> The error is `linux_trace` is not defined

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
require('dotenv').config();
const URI = process.env.MONGO_URL;
mongoose.connect(
  URI,
 
  (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to mongodb');
  }
);

linux_trace.find(function (err, adminLogins) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(adminLogins)})
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with  your code is that you didn't define `linux_trace` as a variable in javascript.

To get access to a model in a mongo database that already has a collection, you can run something like this

```
const query = function (err, adminLogins) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(adminLogins)};
mongoose.connection.db.collection('linux_trace', function (err, collection) {
       collection.find(query).toArray(cb);
   });
```

I got this from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6721306/3173748