# How to define a schema that has nested arrays of objects

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

Update: Wasn't using the collection object in the Schema for mongoose to specify what collection in the database to look at. Once I added the following to the mongoose.Schema it works fine.

```
{
    collection: "maintenances"
}
```

New to mongoose schemas and having trouble with a more advanced object in MongoDB. Getting simple schemas to work seems fine but I have the following MongoDB schema that I am trying to replicate with a mongoose schema.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61310bacd8195bf421751c16"
  },
  "jiraId": "NA-151",
  "summary": "jira summary, trimmed to 50 chars",
  "reason": "maint reason",
  "date": {
    "$date": "2021-07-01T05:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "createdDate": {
    "$date": "2021-08-01T05:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "pre": [
    {
      "hostname": "device1",
      "displayName": "device description",
      "mopData": [
        {
          "command": "show clock",
          "result": "this is the show clock command pre"
        },
        {
          "command": "show version",
          "result": "16.12.1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "post": [
    {
      "hostname": "device1",
      "displayName": "device description",
      "mopData": [
        {
          "command": "show clock",
          "result": "this is the show clock command post"
        },
        {
          "command": "show version",
          "result": "16.12.4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "deviceCount": 1
}
```

I have tried several variations of js but its keeps returning empty arrays when doing a .find() on the collection.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import shortid from "shortid"
import {Main} from "next/document";

const {String, Number, Date} = mongoose.Schema.Types;

const MaintenanceMopData = new mongoose.Schema({
    command: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    result: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const MaintenancePrePostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hostname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mopData: [MaintenanceMopData],
})

const MaintenanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    jiraId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    summary: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    reason: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    maintDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: false
    },
    createdDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: false
    },
    pre: [MaintenancePrePostSchema],
    post: [MaintenancePrePostSchema],
    deviceCount: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    }
})

export default mongoose.models.Maintenance || mongoose.model('Maintenance', MaintenanceSchema)
```

Is this correct or what is the proper way to implement schema that has nested arrays of objects?

Comment: From what I could tell, there is no problem with your schema definition.  Could you maybe share the code you used to test with?

Comment: Wasn't matching the model to the correct name of the collection. Which brings me to how you define what collection in a database if it has multiple?

Comment: Figured it out. Need to use the collection object to define what collection to look at. Was trying to find from a database with multiple collections.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794834/how-to-access-a-preexisting-collection-with-mongoose