# How do i display my data from MongoDB Atlas in my node js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, collections

I am trying to display data from sample collection thats in mongoDB Atlas. i have connected to the server, retrieved the data. But the problem is i cannot choose specific data. if i do it says **undefined**.

Here is the pic and code for better understanding:

MY MOVIE MODEL movie.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
require("dotenv").config();

const mongoDB_API = process.env.MONGODB_API_KEY;

const mflixDB = mongoose.createConnection(mongoDB_API).useDb("sample_mflix");

const Movies = mflixDB.model("Movie", new Schema({}), "movies");
module.exports = Movies;
```

I used the code via [mongoose access preexisting collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794834/how-to-access-a-preexisting-collection-with-mongoose)

Snippet of MongoDB ATLAS:
[image: mongoDB Snippet]

my app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const _ =require('lodash');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static('public'));


const Movies = require('./model/mflix/movies');

app.get("/movies",async (req, res) => {
    const ourMovies = await Movies.find().sort({'date': -1}).limit(2);
    console.log("WE recieved: \n")
    console.log(ourMovies);
    const titles =[];
    ourMovies.forEach( x=>{
         console.log(x._id, x.title)
    })
    res.render("movies", { recievedList: ourMovies });
  });
```

the output:
[image: output of this code]

As u can see x.title is undefined instead of respective title.

I cannot access any info other than _id.
Is this because i didn't properly defined my schema for the model ?
How do i fix this?

Comment: **SSOLVED**
I think the Schema part is not needed. i tried this :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40229995/12110768)

It got the data just like the above pics and i can also individual data like title, plot and so on. Cheers!

Comment: Can anyone still explain why it is undefined and how to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing more on this answer([this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794834/how-to-access-a-preexisting-collection-with-mongoose)) and decided to try other ways to do similar thing

Solution from this: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40229995/12110768), i tried that soliton and added it in my code in following manner:

in app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const _ =require('lodash');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(express.static('public'));

//we dont really need this (UNUSED)
const Movies = require('./model/mflix/movies');

const mongoDB_API = process.env.MONGODB_API_KEY;

const mflixDB = mongoose.createConnection(mongoDB_API).useDb("sample_mflix");

app.get("/movies", async (req, res) => {
  const collection = mflixDB.collection("movies");
  collection
    .find({})
    .limit(2)
    .toArray(function (err, data) {
      console.log("\nour data:");
      console.log(data); // it will print your collection data
        data.forEach(x=>{
            console.log(`Id: ${x._id} \t title: ${x.title}`)
        })
    });

  const ourMovies = await Movies.find().sort({ date: -1 }).limit(2);
  // console.log("WE recieved: \n")
  // console.log(ourMovies);
  // const titles =[];
  // ourMovies.forEach( x=>{
  //      console.log(x._id, x.title)
  // })
  res.render("movies", { recievedList: ourMovies });
});
```

The output:It shows title (and not *undefined* like above question)
[image]